# merging table and updating one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle, I need to merge two queries, but i would like to add one column at the end showing where i set the value to "query2", which mean it was a result coming from query2.

there is my example so far

```
select t1.* , t2.* , 0 isdefault
  from table1 t1, table2 t2 
 where ....                  
union           
select t1.*,t2.*, t3.isdefault    
  from table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
 where ... 
   and t3.inactive = 0;
```

Comment: An OUTER JOIN may do what you need more efficiently than a UNION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statically define the value, like you provided for the `isdefault`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, 0 isdefault, 'query1' AS whichQuery
  FROM table1 t1, 
       table2 t2 
 WHERE ...
UNION           
SELECT t1.*,t2.*, t3.isdefault, 'query2' AS whichQuery
  FROM table1 t1, 
       table2 t2,
       table3 t3
 WHERE ... 
   AND t3.inactive = 0;
```

Comment: now I have duplicate records one with query1 and the other with query2, how to remove one of them? because t3.isdefault can be 0

Comment: @user1111111: You'll have to provide the query details, but I believe you're likely getting a cartesian product from either query... or there's more than one child record associated to the parent.